# update location in the background

Tags: android, json, multithreading, google-maps

I am using the code below for location updates:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 500, locationListener);
```

And the json to update location to server :

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(updatelocation);
    try {
        json = (JSONObject) json.get("updated");
        //location is updated
    } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Network issues.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Is the above code correct or is there any other way to update location in the background ?

Please help me out .
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AsyncTask for this: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Otherwise, you might block the UI thread, which is bad.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Can this code be run within this : new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      try {

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

Comment: Another thing : I dont want the user to know the updates in the background is happening.

Comment: Th AsynTask is a convenient and transparent means to run a task asynchronously. You don't need to take care of threading. This is done for you. Just start the task and you are done.

Comment: @JamesPatrick yes you can use `runOnUiThread()` too for updating UI while doing threading process.

Comment: And how do I update without showing progessDialog ? when doing other task simultaneously in the aboove requirement?  Let say I am searching for location and at the same time location update thread has begun it should handle both without interfering each others process .How to do that?

Comment: @PareshMayani So What I am doing above within runOnUiThread() is correct ?

Comment: @PareshMayani,Dan : And how do I update without showing progessDialog ? when doing other task simultaneously in the aboove requirement? Let say I am searching for location and at the same time location update thread has begun it should handle both without interfering each others process .How to do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you do not show a progressDialog, then there will ne bo progressDialog.

Comment: @Dan So the onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress),onPreExecute() and protected void onPostExecute(Long result)  is left blank and doinBackground is where my json code goes .Right ?

Comment: @Dan Sorry Sir for the trouble .

Comment: Yes. Plase also see the link I posted.

Comment: And the update to server happens even if the user is performing another task right :Like view through the listview. Right ?

Comment: I saw the link you posted and I have used it in the code before but Will it do the same when another async thread is running simultaneously ?

Comment: @Dan Thank you Sir for all the inputs.Really appreciate the help.